# Generate unique sequence numbers java

Tags: java, list, collections

I generate lists based on Map,

```
       Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```

complete code is here: https://repl.it/L3cv/0

Result of the code:

```
      list1: [account_number, account_number, account_number, account_number, Amount, Amount, Amount, Amount]
      list2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 400, 500, 700]
```

Desired result: (generating unique sequence/id based on list2)

```
      list3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In the code, I tried to add 'sequence_number', but it just gives the incremental value [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

```
        sequence_number = 0;
        for (final Integer val : value) {
            sequence_number++;
            list3.add(key);
            list4.add(val);
        }
```

but this does not give me the desired result. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what problem you are trying to solve. This is what I think you try to achieve.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(4);
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list2.add(100);
    list2.add(400);
    list2.add(500);
    list2.add(700);

    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    map.put ("account_number", list1);
    map.put ("Amount", list2);

    System.out.println(map);

    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String lastkey = null;
    int sequence = 0;
    for (final Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        final String key = entry.getKey();
        final List<Integer> value = entry.getValue();

        for (final Integer val : value) {
            list3.add(key);
            if(lastkey == null||lastkey!=key){
              sequence = 1;
              lastkey = key;
            } 
            list4.add(sequence++);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(list3);
    System.out.println(list4);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions, based on your answer to this question:

"Does the first list always contain pairs of items? Means, it always has an even number of entries, so if there are 12 entries, you expect 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6?"

If yes, your solution goes like this:

```
 int halflist = list1.size() / 2;
 int sequencenumber = 0;
 for (...) {
    sequencenumber++;
    // add your stuff
    if (sequencenumber == halflist) sequencenumber = 0;
 }
```

This will raise the value 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4.
It could be done with modulo and more fancy code too, but the simple increment here should keep it understandable.

- If no, please provide more details, what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this is helpful as well but its adding 0 like [2,3,4,0,2,3,4,0]

Comment: No I don't think so. It starts with zero, but increments as first line in the for... loop. So the first value is 1.
The last line of the for loop is the if... statement which resets to zero (and again increments as first line of the next iteration).
do you have the lines in the exact above order?

Answer (score 0):

> Desired result: (generating unique sequence/id based on list2)

Did you mean `list1`? Because the example you have given - `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, is of `list1`.

Then, if you want to restart the sequence ID-Counter over the size of `list1`, you could use `%`-operator:

```
    for (final Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        final String key = entry.getKey();
        final List<Integer> value = entry.getValue();
        for (int i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) { //<<< We need an index.
            list3.add(key);
            list4.add(list1.get(i % list1.size()));  //<<< Change this!
        }
    }
```

[Your code-link, edited with changes.](https://repl.it/L3cv/1)